# Can't add Target database to Cloud Control

Tags: database, oracle, agent, cloudcontrol, oracle-enterprise-manager

I deployed my agent to my host and i wanted to monitor my database.

Agent and host is running.
[image]

However, it could not find the databases and all listeners.

### [image]

[image]

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to select the agent from the search bar next to the Host icon in the discovery page.

2) Go to the database host and check if the Oracle listener is runnning on the node.(tnslsnr).

3) If the listener is not up, start the listener and make sure its registered with the oracle database instance and try discovery again.

4) If this does not work, you can manually add a database to enterprise manager by providing all properties (e.g. Oracle Home, host, port, listener name, etc).